# C#: POST request with BASIC authentication mixes QUERY_STRING and REQUEST_METHOD in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, post, webclient, basic-authentication

I have a problem with sending a POST request from C# to a PHP script on my Apache (Windows) server. Everything works fine, unless I instruct Apache to require a valid user using BASIC authentication through a `.htaccess` file.

But let's put things in order. I'm using the following code to send a list of key/value pairs to my PHP script using HTTP-POST:

```
NameValueCollection nameValues = new NameValueCollection();
nameValues["operation"] = ...;
nameValues["order"] = ...;
nameValues["status"] = ...;
nameValues["comment"] = ...;
nameValues["user"] = ...;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
try
{
    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri(PERFORM_URL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(PERFORM_USER, PERFORM_PASSWORD));

    webClient.Credentials = credentialCache;
    byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues(PERFORM_URL, "POST", nameValues);
    string responseString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
}
finally
{
    webClient.Dispose();
}
```

The PHP script on the server looks like this:

```
<?php

print_r($_SERVER);

?>
```

So I just output some header information here. I turn off basic authentication in my `htaccess` file, everything's fine. When I turn it on, however, I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [REMOTE_USER] => ****
    [AUTH_TYPE] => Basic
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => operation=updatestatus&order=185&status=17&comment=Test&user=somenamePOST
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    ...
    [PHP_AUTH_USER] => ****
    [PHP_AUTH_PW] => ****
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1286889387
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
```

Where, the `REQUEST_METHOD` contains all the parameters + the appended `POST`. This is wrong. What can I do about it? I've also read and tried solutions, where people used `HttpWebRequest` using the `PreAuthenticate` property - but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: What's the actual response on the wire? Knowing that would help tell if the bug was in the C# part or the PHP part.

Comment: My C# code receives the output I gave in the last code fragment. I didn't debug the actual HTTP communication - how would I do that? What is it that you want to see?

Comment: The best thing to do would probably be to get Wireshark going on the network between them, and watching the raw TCP traffic to see if it's even valid HTTP that C# is sending...  If not, you at least know it's in C# (either your code, or a bug in the library that you're using)...

Comment: Well, my script is being called and I'm also getting a reply. It is basically the same problem stated here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856052/c-rest-client-merging-post-and-request-method), only that the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting the question without giving a proper reason. I love you people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. Didn't get it to work, but implemented by own authentication, so I do not need the basic authentication anymore. Would still be interested in a working solution, in case anyone has an idea ;-)