# Post an outlook attachment stream to a rest api

Tags: c#, rest

I am developping an outlook add-in, i have to upload mailitem attachment using rest api. First i save the attachment to a temp directory and i create a streamreader to that file, how can i post this stream because if i don´t post the stream it creates me empty files with just the specified name:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= this.Attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                    var fileName = this.Attachments[i].FileName;
                    Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(Path.GetTempPath() + fileName);
                    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Path.GetTempPath() + fileName);

                }
```

what i must do to achieve it, i need some help. Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# REST client sending data using POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856052/c-sharp-rest-client-sending-data-using-post)